# Probability that Brownian Motion hits a point

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I have some question regarding the notation from the book on Brownian Motion by Peres and Mörters found online [here](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Eneiningr/MP.pdf). They define $\mathbb{P}_x$ to mean a probability measure which makes $(B(t))$ a Brownian motion started at $x$ (p. 36).

In Corollary 2.26 on p. 47 in the book on Brownian Motion they want to show that $\mathbb{P}_x\{y\in B(0,1]\} = 0$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$. If $\Omega$ is the underlying probability space on which the Brownian motion is defined this means that for fixed $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$\mathbb{P}\{\omega\in \Omega:y\in B((0,1],\omega)\} = 0$$
where $B$ is a Brownian motion starting at $x$.
They do this by first showing, using their notation, that $\mathbb{P}_x\{y\in B[0,1]\} = 0$ for Lebesgue- almost every $x$ where $y$ is arbitrary. They then say that $\mathbb{P}_{B(\varepsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\} = 0$ almost surely where $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary.

**Now I have some trouble understanding what $\mathbb{P}_{B(\varepsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}$ means.**

I read this notation as follows: the event consists of all $\omega$ such that $y\in B([0,1],\omega)$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion starting at $B(\varepsilon,\omega)$. However I don't see how to make sense of this based on previous definitions. Previously Brownian motions start at fixed non-random points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore saying that a Brownian motion should start from the point where the Brownian motion hits at $\varepsilon$ is also strange, since in defining the Brownian motion we need to simultaneously know where it hits at $\varepsilon$.

Do they mean that if $\tilde{B}$ is another Brownian motion, then almost surely for $\hat{\omega}$ it holds that
$$\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{B}(\varepsilon,\hat{\omega})}\{\omega: y\in B([0,1],\omega)\} = 0$$
for this I see follows from the previous result. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Your notation are definitely not standard. What means $\mathbb P_x\{y\in B(0,1]\}$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: The notation is from the book by Mörters and Peres. With $\mathbb{P}_x\{y\in B(0,1]\}$ they mean that $B$ is a Brownian motion starting at $x$.

Comment: They write on p. 36 "Throughout this book we write $\mathbb{P}_x$ for the probability measure which makes the $d$-dimensional process $\{B(t):t\geq 0\}$ a Brownian motion started in $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$". But I think that the notation is a bit confusing. So with this the event is simply $\{\omega\in \Omega: y\in B((0,1],\omega)\}$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion starting at $x$ where $y$ and $x$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Ok sorry, I tried to answer the question but I was unclear, I will edit the question adding more details

Comment: Is the question better stated now? I initially wrote the question assuming that the notation was standard since I do not have a lot of background in Brownian motion and hence did not know if the book followed common notation or not

Comment: Now it makes more sense. So $\mathbb P_x\{y\in B(0,1]\}$ is the probability that $(B_t)$ pass through $y$ in time at most $1$ given it start at $x$.

Comment: Yes precisely :)

Comment: So according to your question, they mean that for almost every $\tilde \omega\in \Omega $, $$\mathbb P_{B(\varepsilon ,\tilde \omega )}\{\omega \in \Omega \mid y\in B([0,1],\omega ) \}=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Now I have some trouble understanding what $\mathbb{P}_{B(\varepsilon)}\{y\in B[0,1]\}$ means.**

It is nothing but $\mathbb{P}_{x}\{y\in B[0,1]\}|_{x=B(\varepsilon)}$.

> I read this notation as follows: the event consists of all $\omega$ such that $y\in B([0,1],\omega)$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion starting at $B(\varepsilon,\omega)$.

No.  The event precisely consists of all $\omega$ such that $y \in B([0,1],\omega)$. For instance, if $B$ is defined canonically (i.e. with $\Omega = C([0,1];\mathbb R^2)$ and $B(\cdot,\omega) =\omega(\cdot)$), then this event is nothing else but the set of functions attaining value $y$ at some point. This has nothing to do with the probability $\mathbb P_{x}$ (actually, probabilit**ies**, since there are many of them, and they are mutually singular). Naturally, since the value $\mathbb P_x(A)$ is zero for almost all $x$ and since the law of $B(\varepsilon)$ is absolutely continuous, then $\mathbb P_{B(\varepsilon)}(A) = 0$ almost surely.

Actually, the authors are indeed a bit sloppy here: as I've already mentioned, there are many probability measures, so "almost surely" may a priori sound pretty ambiguous. A diligent way of writing this is "for any $x$, $\mathbb P_{B(\varepsilon)}(A) = 0 \ $   $\ \mathbb P_x$-almost surely". And they are using precisely this when they write further (thanks to the Markov property and homogeneity) that
$$
\mathbb P_x (y \in B ([\varepsilon,1])) = \mathbb E_x \mathbb P_{B(\varepsilon)} (y \in B ([0,1-\varepsilon]))=0.
$$

---

Some elaboration of the last formula:
$$
\mathbb P_x (y \in B ([\varepsilon,1])) = \mathbb P_x (\{\exists t\in [\varepsilon,1]: B(t) = y\}) = \mathbb P_x (\{\exists t\in [\varepsilon,1]: B(t) - B(\varepsilon) + B(\varepsilon) = y\})
$$
Thanks to the ($\mathbb P_x$-)independence of $B(t) - B(\varepsilon)$ and $B(\varepsilon)$, this is equal to
$$
\mathbb E_x \mathbb P_x (\{\exists t\in [\varepsilon,1]: B(t) - B(\varepsilon) + z = y\})\big|_{z = B(\varepsilon)}.
$$
Now using the fact that (under $\mathbb P_x$) $B(t) - B(\varepsilon)$ is, up to a time shift by $\varepsilon$, a Brownian motion starting from $0$, we can further rewrite this as
$$\mathbb E_x \mathbb P_0 (\{\exists s\in [0,1-\varepsilon]: B(s) + z = y\})\big|_{z = B(\varepsilon)} = \mathbb E_x \mathbb P_z (\{\exists s\in [0,1-\varepsilon]: B(s) = y\})\big|_{z = B(\varepsilon)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, however I have one thing I don't understand on the first part. The Brownian motion starts at $x$ and hence $B$ depends on $x$. When you set $x = B(\varepsilon)$ doesn't the right-hand side depend on $x$? I also do not understand how to conclude the last equality using the Markov property. Could you enlighten me on how this is done?

I have a bit of trouble unraveling the meaning of $$\mathbb{E}_x\Big[\mathbb{P}_x(y\in B([0,1-\varepsilon]))\vert_{x = B(\varepsilon)}\Big]$$

Comment: "The Brownian motion starts at $x$ and hence $B$ depends on $x$." Not exactly. It is rather measure $\mathbb P_x$ is such that the distribution of $B$ under this measure is supported by functions starting from $x$. As I mentioned, $\Omega$ and $B$ have usually nothing to do with $\mathbb P_x$, e.g. with the canonical construction I've given.

Comment: Concerning the meaning, see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. I’ll go over it this evening and accept  it when I’ve gone through the details. Thank you very much for your time